# BlackBerry Cascades prints {Error} when I use Share action

Tags: qt, blackberry

I'm developing an app for *black-berry*, and one of its functionalies is to share a 'note' to other apps, so its text can be used (on an e-mail, for example), but it keeps printing "{Error}" where it should print the message.

I used the following:

```
actions: [
    InvokeActionItem {
        ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
        id: shareNoteActionItem
        query {
            mimeType: "text/plain"
            data: Qt._filesController.stoba(noteContent)
            invokeActionId: "bb.action.SHARE"
        }
    }
]
```

Where `Qt._filesController` is an object of `FilesController` class, and `stoba()` is the following function:

```
QByteArray FilesController::stoba(QString str) {
    return str.toLocal8Bit();
}
```

And noteContent is `QString`. I've tried other conversions, but none seems to work. What should i do?

Comment: How do you bind your QML to this object "Qt._filesController.stoba(noteContent)".  As far as I can see, it will looking for an Object called Qt.  Have a look at this page for approaches to expose your FileController class and its stoba function to your QML: http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/index.html

Comment: Well, its been told me that Qt is a kind of global table, to which I could add content freely. So i did:
`Qt._filesController = _filesController`
in main.qml, and
`FilesController *filesController = FilesController::getInstance();`
`qml->setContextProperty("_filesController", filesController);`
in applicationui.cpp.

It works, so the binding is not the problem, apparently.

Comment: I noticed it to be a bigger problem inside the project itself. It means the problem is not in the part I put here.

Comment: "its been told me that Qt is a kind of global table" - and do you find that documented anywhere?  I can't, so I don't think that is true.  " in applicationui.cpp. It works, so the binding is not the problem"  You are not trying to use it in your c code, it is the binding to QML that is causing the problem here.  I suggest you implement the approaches given on the page I referenced, in this case you need to look at the section entitled "Exposing C++ objects to QML", make sure FilesController uses the Q_OBJECT macro, and Q_INVOKABLE for the method(s) that will be invoked from QML.

Comment: I meant that I succesfully used `Qt._filesController` in other parts of the code, Including that specific QML page. The problem is NOT the biding. I did all the necessary so I could use that function. The problem is yet unknown, but I did see that `FilesController::getTextContent()`, the function that gets the text, returns the string '{Error}' because I parse the wrong file path. I don't know why this happens, and I'm working on solving that. About the `Qt` object, I can't find it documented too... but you should try it yourself and see... it works!

Comment: @PeterStrange actually, here it is: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qml-qt.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have had a quick look and can see that it provides access to various Qt services.  I don't see how it provides a link to any user specific code, but then I have not looked hard.  And apologies, I thought the problem you were having was getting to the stoba() method, not the data picked up by the sharing application.  I'll do some research on that before posting next time!